# How can I create new page normally in Latex?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} %Sets the default text size to 11pt and class to article.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{vwcol} 
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{array, xcolor}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{sectsty}
  \sectionfont{\fontsize{10}{10}\normalfont}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage{afterpage}


\topmargin=0in %length of margin at the top of the page (1 inch added by default)
  \oddsidemargin=-0.18in %length of margin on sides for odd pages
  \evensidemargin=-0.18in %length of margin on sides for even pages
  \textwidth=7in %How wide you want your text to be
  \marginparwidth=0.2in
  \headheight=0pt %1in margins at top and bottom (1 inch is added to this value by default)
  \headsep=0pt %Increase to increase white space in between headers and the top of the page
  \textheight=12in %How tall the text body is allowed to be on each page
  \textheight=3in %How tall the text body is allowed to be on each page
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{longtable}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.15\textwidth}
\hfill \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{cvphoto}
\end{wrapfigure}
\hfill Ender Ayhan Rencüzoğulları                               

\hfillÇağdaşkent, Birlik Evleri no:4

\hfill 33230, Mersin/Turkey

\hfill 90 505 8980764

\hfill enderayhan@gmail.com

\noindent
\\\\
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.76\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
\section*{\normalfont EDUCATION}  
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
09.2009 - 01.2016&B.Sc. in Mechanical Engineering, Gaziantep University, Gaziantep/Turkey\\[5pt]
&Concentration: Design solution for machinery elements, manufacturing. Graduation Thesis: Gear tooth geometry and modeling via MATLAB. Voluntary Project: Tooth stiffness calculation of spur gear via C++. Compulsory projects: Non-contact digital tachometer system; bearing, gear, spring, shaft and welding design. Provided teaching assistance to junior classes for engineering drawing. Lab-works: Hydraulic systems; turning, milling and welding; techniques of measurement of heating value, temperature, force, speed, power, pressure and flow. GPA: 73/100 or 2.30/4.00 \\[5pt]
09.2005 - 06.2009&Science, Mersin Ticaret ve Sanayi Odası Anatolian High School, Mersin/Turkey\\[5pt]
&Physics: Good; Mathematics: Good; Chemistry: Good; Geometry: Good, German: Good. Final Grade: Good\\[5pt]
\end{longtable}

\section*{\normalfont EXPERIENCE}  
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
09.2015 - 01.2016&Intern Engineer, Ermaksan Machine Gear Spare Parts Industry, Ankara/Turkey\\[5pt]
&Wrote functional software to model 2D gear geometry with pinpoint accuracy (graduation thesis). Incorporated new algorithm into the software and achieved 20\% increase in speed. Provided ease of 3D modeling of spur and helical gears in SolidWorks. Practiced various manufacturing techniques such as hobbing, grinding, CNC drilling, CNC turning and assembly in production of reducer and hydraulic coupling.\\[5pt]
08.2014 - 09.2014&Intern Engineer, Turkish Aerospace Industry, Ankara/Turkey\\[5pt]
&Expanded undergraduate engineering knowledges through continuing industrial practices and assignments about manufacturing, assembly, chemical process, heat treatment, non-destructive testing, foreign object damage, occupational health and safety. Led coordination of an intern engineer group.\\[5pt]
08.2013 - 09.2013&Intern Engineer, Orpaş Laser, Ankara/Turkey\\[5pt]
&Practiced direct machine shop skills: CNC turning, bending and extrusion. Improved interpersonal and communication skills.\\[5pt]
09.2013&Intern Engineer, Her-İş Casting Shop, Mersin/Turkey\\[5pt]
&Practiced sand casting in manufacturing of spare parts.\\[5pt]
08.2012 - 09.2012&Intern Engineer, Gaziantep University Laboratories, Gaziantep/Turkey\\[5pt]
&Assembled internal combustion engines of bus and automobile provided vivid demonstration of concepts in energy conversion and dynamics of machinery classes. Worked with technically advanced, trained and coordinated work-team including Professors and talented technicians to practice theoretical engineering knowledges in manufacturing of prototype of artillery by turning, hand leveling and milling. Practiced different welding technologies provided demonstration for welding design project in Machinery Elements class.\\[5pt]
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A table (`tabular`)  cannot be broken over pages. Try `longtable` instead.

Comment: A simple list (maybe modiefied using `enumitem`) *might* be better suited for your needs.

Comment: I have tried `longtable` but problem was not solved @Johannes_B. Probably I made some mistake since I am new to Latex. Would you please give me more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative for tabular material with CVs are lists. Lists are often much more simple.

[image: enderCvList]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} %Sets the default text size to 11pt and class to article.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,paperheight=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{10}{10}\normalfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setlist[itemize]{labelwidth=8em,leftmargin=8.5em,rightmargin=0cm,align=parleft}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \raggedleft
 Ender Ayhan Rencüzoğulları                               \par
Çağdaşkent, Birlik Evleri no:4\par
 33230, Mersin/Turkey\par
 90 505 8980764\par
 enderayhan@gmail.com
 \end{minipage}
    \includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}

\section{EDUCATION}  
\begin{itemize}
\item [09.2009 -- 01.2016] B.Sc. in Mechanical Engineering, Gaziantep University, Gaziantep/Turkey

    Concentration: Design solution for machinery elements, manufacturing. Graduation Thesis: Gear tooth geometry and modeling via MATLAB. Voluntary Project: Tooth stiffness calculation of spur gear via C++. Compulsory projects: Non-contact digital tachometer system; bearing, gear, spring, shaft and welding design. Provided teaching assistance to junior classes for engineering drawing. Lab-works: Hydraulic systems; turning, milling and welding; techniques of measurement of heating value, temperature, force, speed, power, pressure and flow. GPA: 73/100 or 2.30/4.00 
\item [09.2005 -- 06.2009] Science, Mersin Ticaret ve Sanayi Odası Anatolian High School, Mersin/Turkey

    Physics: Good; Mathematics: Good; Chemistry: Good; Geometry: Good, German: Good. Final Grade: Good
\end{itemize}

\section{EXPERIENCE}  
\begin{itemize}
    \item[09.2015 -- 01.2016] Intern Engineer, Ermaksan Machine Gear Spare Parts Industry, Ankara/Turkey

    Wrote functional software to model 2D gear geometry with pinpoint accuracy (graduation thesis). Incorporated new algorithm into the software and achieved 20\,\% increase in speed. Provided ease of 3D modeling of spur and helical gears in SolidWorks. Practiced various manufacturing techniques such as hobbing, grinding, CNC drilling, CNC turning and assembly in production of reducer and hydraulic coupling.
\item[08.2014 -- 09.2014] Intern Engineer, Turkish Aerospace Industry, Ankara/Turkey

    Expanded undergraduate engineering knowledges through continuing industrial practices and assignments about manufacturing, assembly, chemical process, heat treatment, non-destructive testing, foreign object damage, occupational health and safety. Led coordination of an intern engineer group.
\item[08.2013 -- 09.2013] Intern Engineer, Orpaş Laser, Ankara/Turkey

    Practiced direct machine shop skills: CNC turning, bending and extrusion. Improved interpersonal and communication skills.
\item[09.2013] Intern Engineer, Her-İş Casting Shop, Mersin/Turkey

    Practiced sand casting in manufacturing of spare parts.
\item[08.2012 -- 09.2012] Intern Engineer, Gaziantep University Laboratories, Gaziantep/Turkey

    Assembled internal combustion engines of bus and automobile provided vivid demonstration of concepts in energy conversion and dynamics of machinery classes. Worked with technically advanced, trained and coordinated work-team including Professors and talented technicians to practice theoretical engineering knowledges in manufacturing of prototype of artillery by turning, hand leveling and milling. Practiced different welding technologies provided demonstration for welding design project in Machinery Elements class.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I solved the problem by adding new page after the tabular. However, I appreciate for your helps.

Comment: @EnderA.Rencüzoğulları Completely off-topic, but have a closer look at the dash between the dates in my example. You have to use `--` instead of a simple hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Normal tabular material cannot be broken over several pages, you have to use `longtable` for that.

A screenshot with very small pages:

[image: enderCvTable]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} %Sets the default text size to 11pt and class to article.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{vwcol} 
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{array, xcolor}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{sectsty}
  \sectionfont{\fontsize{10}{10}\normalfont}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage{afterpage}

  \topmargin=0in %length of margin at the top of the page (1 inch added by default)
  \oddsidemargin=-0.18in %length of margin on sides for odd pages
  \evensidemargin=-0.18in %length of margin on sides for even pages
  \textwidth=7in %How wide you want your text to be
  \marginparwidth=0.2in
  \headheight=0pt %1in margins at top and bottom (1 inch is added to this value by default)
  \headsep=0pt %Increase to increase white space in between headers and the top of the page
  \textheight=12in %How tall the text body is allowed to be on each page
  \textheight=3in %How tall the text body is allowed to be on each page
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \usepackage{longtable}

  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
  \begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.15\textwidth}
      \hfill \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}
  \end{wrapfigure}

  %text, text, text...

  \definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.2\textwidth}}
  \newcolumntype{R}{p{0.75\textwidth}}
  \newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

  \section{EDUCATION}  
  \begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
2016 & Master of the Universe \\
      %text text text...
  \end{longtable}

  \section{EXPERIENCE}  
  \begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
      %text text text ...

  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
```

Apart from that, reading a LaTeX introduction will get you a better start than using a bad template.

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B, unforunately it still gives the same result.

Comment: Please run the example i have given. It works. Something on your machine/your document is different and we don't know what. Please provide a minimal working example and add it to the question on top.

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B, I editted the code and wrote entire code above. Would you please run by changing the image name? then you will see that every section is written on different page.

Comment: @EnderA.Rencüzoğulları A break can only occur *between* table lines, not within a cell.

Comment: You mean there is not a way that I can break the table at the first page when text comes to the bottom and continue with the second page, right? @Johannes_B

Comment: You can ask a second question asking how to get a list with that grey rule between left and right part.

Comment: I personally consider tabulars as often critical for CV writing, because of that restriction of tables. But almost every CV template uses tabular stuff instead of lists, which is a pity.

Comment: okay, thank you for your effort. @Johannes_B